# My edge start up very slowly. How to solve it?

Tags: microsoft-edge

When I close edge chromium completely (close all tabs), it will take about 8s to start up next time. chrome has the same problem.

I have asked this on the Microsoft community. they told me to create a new windows account. It works, edge start up immediately in the new account. 
If there is a way to fix this problem in the old account?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the Microsoft Edge slowly issue, here are some things you can try.

1. Clear all browsing data

   Select **Settings and more** > **History** > **Clear browsing data**. Select **All time** under Time Range; select all boxes, and then select **Clear now**.
2. Close other tabs, extensions, and apps

   Your computer may have run out of memory, and can't load the site while also running your apps, extensions, and programs.

   To free up memory:

   1). Close other apps or programs that are running. (Select Setting and more > Apps > close them)
   2). Pause any downloads.
   3). Uninstall extensions you don't need. (Select Setting and more > Extensions > disable/remove them)
3. Restart Microsoft Edge
4. Reinstall Microsoft Edge

Comment: I have tried all of these. they are ineffective. my memory is ample.

Comment: @WhiteWing, about the windows account, do you mean [the profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEWl5.png)? From your description, after changing account the edge works well, so, I think perhaps the issue is related to the personal data (such as extensions, Temporary Files or browser data), after clearing them, it browser might be faster.

Comment: It's the local user like Administrator. I have tried what you say, but it don't work. In the new user, I sign in Edge with the same Microsoft account and synced the profile. Edge has not slow down.

Comment: Try to open the Task Manager and check whether there have some running processes which will use much CPU or Memory? If there has high usage process, try to close it. Besides, here is an article about [How To Fix Slow Microsoft Edge](https://www.webnots.com/how-to-fix-slow-microsoft-edge/), you could check it.